# Is there any use in creating a r-value reference variable using std::move(). [C++]

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Can someone help mend my understanding of `std::move`?

I thought that if an r-value reference goes out of scope what it references would too if it was assigned using the `std::move` operator. Why is that not the case in the below code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string one = "1 - one";
    string two = "2 - two";
    {
        //not as expected
        string & lValRef = one;
        string && rValRef = std::move(two);
        string newS(rValRef);
    }
    cout << "one : " << one << endl;
    cout << "two : " << two << endl;
    {
        //as expected
        string temp(std::move(one));
        string tempAssignment;
        tempAssignment = std::move(two);
    }
    cout << "one : " << one << endl;
    cout << "two : " << two << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can fiddle with it [here](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/m86B08).

I always thought using `std::move` was a way to leave objects in a 'deletable state'. So I was surprised that 'two' printed anything out the first time. Is there any use in creating a && r-value reference as I did ('rValRef')? [I understand that a `std::move()` would be required around my 'rValRef' for it to work as desired].

Below is my own code that I used to help me understand this better. Please play around with it if you desire :) Code [here](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/FRrvqo).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class SimpleClass {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream & s,const SimpleClass & rhs);
private:
    vector<char> data;
public:
    SimpleClass(initializer_list<char> lst):data(lst.size()) {
        copy(lst.begin(),lst.end(),data.begin());
    }
    SimpleClass(size_t dim = 0):data(dim){};
    virtual ~SimpleClass() = default;
    SimpleClass(const SimpleClass & rhs) = default;
    SimpleClass & operator=(const SimpleClass & rhs) = default;
    SimpleClass(SimpleClass && rhs):data(move(rhs.data)){};
    SimpleClass & operator=(SimpleClass && rhs){
        if (this != &rhs){
            this->data = move(rhs.data);
            return *this;
        }
    }
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream & s,const SimpleClass & rhs){
    for (size_t i = 0; i != rhs.data.size(); ++i)
        s << rhs.data[i];

    return s;
}
int main()
{
    SimpleClass one = {'o','n','e'};
    SimpleClass two = {'t','w','o'};
    {
        SimpleClass & lValRef = one;
        SimpleClass && rValRef = std::move(two);
    }
    cout << "one : " << one << endl;
    cout << "two : " << two << endl;
    {
        SimpleClass temp(std::move(one));
        SimpleClass tempAssignment;
        tempAssignment = std::move(two);
    }
    cout << "one : " << one << endl;
    cout << "two : " << two << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the language worked the way you suggest, it would be very hard to use. Code like yours would fail and it would be hard to avoid. So instead, the language requires you to explicitly use `std::move` at the point where you want the name refer to an invalid object.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hmm, I don't necessarily agree that it would cause the code to fail if you could have 'floating' r-value' references that you could pass around and 'collapse' (or however you want to put it) where you desire. Can you explain what you mean by fail? But I definitely think we can/should be grateful that C++ requires 'std::move()' to be stated explicitly for the general readability of code, debugging etc.

Comment: Think about trying to use such references -- stuff like `string a = b; a += "."; a += b;`. You would need to put some kind of `std::copy` or `std::keep` everywhere *but* the last use. That's just worse, so the language made the other decision to require an indication at last use.

Comment: "I always thought using std::move was a way to leave objects in a 'deletable state'. "  - no, **doing a move operation** is a way to leave objects in a deletable state.  `std::move` does not do any operation, it transforms the value category of the argument so that when you use it as argument to another operation, that operation becomes a move operation.   But in this case you did not use it as any such argument.

Comment: `string && rValRef = std::move(two);` is exactly the same as `string &rValRef = two;`  , except for the result of `decltype`.  The declared type of a reference only affects how it binds; but once they are bound all variables are the same

Comment: @M.M Ok, that makes complete sense! So in essence 'std::move()' can be thought of as a kind of cast, not an operator. Right?

Comment: @JasoonS Exactly, `std::move` is a kind of cast. It's equivalent to `static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)`.

Comment: cast operators are operators :) I meant "operation" in a more abstract sense in my earlier comment

Comment: in general, `std::move` is just a way to say to compiler "you can take this object instead of copy of it". Yet, default behavior (when you don't specify move versions of methods) is to make copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing to understand here is that reference type is a separate concept from value category.

```
string && rValRef = std::move(two);
string newS(rValRef);
```

On that second line, the type of `rValRef` is an rvalue reference to `std::string`, but the value category of `rValRef` is lvalue. A good rule-of-thumb for this is if you can take the address of something, it's probably an lvalue. `rValRef` is a named variable which you can take the address of, so is an lvalue.

If you want to actually move from the referencee, you need to call `std::move` again so that the expression has the right value category (specifically, `std::move` returns an xvalue, which is a kind of rvalue):

```
string newS(std::move(rValRef));
```